# Find all the primes from 2 to n, using the Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: python, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I have a word problem I am trying to solve but am getting stuck on a key part.

> **Convert the following English description into Python code.**
>
> Initialize **n** to be 100. Initialize **numbers** to be a list of numbers from **2** to **n**, but not including **n**. With **results** starting as the empty list, repeat the following as long as **numbers** contains any numbers.
>
> - Add the first number in **numbers** to the end of **results**.
> - Remove every number in **numbers** that is evenly divisible by (has no remainder when divided by) the number that you had just added to **results**.
>
> How long is result?
>
> When **n** is 100, the length of **results** is 25.

So far I have understood to set `n = 100`, and a `range(2, 100)`, `results = []` and that the result will be an append situation as in `results.append(numbers[])`, but I am having a mental block figuring the key of "Remove every number in numbers that is divisible by the number that was added to results".

======after a couple minutes=======

**As Michael0x2a said - this is a problem when i have to implement an algorithm that finds all the primes from 2 to n, using the Sieve of Eratosthenes.**

I think I can continue to deal with this problem.

Thank's a lot for your answers guys.

Comment: If it helps, it looks like the question is asking you to implement an algorithm that finds all the primes from 2 to n, using the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking how to go through the list of numbers or how to figure out that a number is divisible by another a number?

Comment: And why is this a "word" problem?

Comment: Reopen please. I've edited with clear explanation what i needed in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n = 100
numbers = range(2,100)
results = []
while len(numbers) > 0:
    results.append(numbers[0])
    numbers = [number for number in numbers if number % results[-1] != 0]
print len(results)
```

Comment: Dear Kyle,
Can you please write a full implementation of your solution? I just trying to figure out how exactly it works. Thanks.

Comment: Thank's for help Kyle.
I've done with your help right that way:

`codedef long_implementation(n):
    numbers = range(2,n)
    results = []
    
    while len(numbers) > 0:
        results.append(numbers[0])
        for number in numbers:
            if number % results[-1] == 0: #
                numbers.remove(number)`

Comment: @Matvey after `results.append(numbers[0])`, `results[-1]` is just `== numbers[0]`; also, `for number in numbers: if number % results[-1] == 0: numbers.remove(number)` is ***trial division***; but it is the same as `for number in range(numbers[0],100,numbers[0]): if number in numbers: numbers.remove(number)` and *that* ***is*** the sieve of Eratosthenes.

Answer (score 2):

The following:

> Add the first number in numbers to the end of results.

...is not the same as:

```
results.append(numbers[])
```

To access the **first** number in a list, you can use the first index.

Thus:

```
numbers[0] ## would be the first "number" in numbers
```

---

Further, to do the following:

> But I am having a mental block figuring the key of "Remove every
>   number in numbers that is divisible by the number that was added to
>   results".

...you will need some way of testing what a number is divisible by, which means you'll need to use modulo:

```
some_number % some_other_number
```

If there's no remainder, the modulo will result in a zero.